# Combining Multiple outputs in single view in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am looking to use asp.net MVC for new project. I looked at different examples at asp.net and over web. I still didn't get answer to , what is the best way to combine output of different models into a single view. For example my home page will contain catgories, locations, snapshots of recent posts. These will come from three different models. Do I create single viewdata with everything in it and messup within view to place content accordingly ?

Answer (score 8):

You create a ViewModel for your homepage... something like...

```
public class MyHomepageViewModel
{
    public Categories MyCategories { get; set; }
    public Locations MyLocations { get; set; }
    public Snapshots MySnapshots { get; set; }

    public MyHomepageViewModel(Categories categories, Locations locations, Snapshots snapshots)
    {
        MyCategories = categories;
        MyLocations = locations;
        MySnapshots = snapshots;
    }
}
```

and then you strongly type your homepage to this view model and you will have access to everything that you need in your view =)

Comment: Thanks Jon... now I actually get what a ViewModel is.

Comment: This is replacing a controller right? If so, where does it go in the asp.net folder structure? In a new folder called ViewModels?

Comment: @George... this would not replace a controller, this would be used by a controller's action to populate a view, you can put it anywhere in the folder structure, I'd usually put them in a ViewModels folder.

Answer (score 3):

You need View Model for this:

```
public class HomeViewModel {
    public IList<Category> Categories;
    public IList<Location> Locations;
    public IList<Snapshot> Snapshots;
    public IList<Post> Recent;
}
```

Your View must be strongly-typed:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<HomeViewModel>" %>

<!-- <% var categories = Model.Categories %> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually create one view model class that aggregates multiple data model classes in this scenario.

I believe view and data should be two different set of objects because sometimes you need to do data trasformations (e.g. formating a decimal from a data model class to a string in currency format in view model) in the controller class before it is sent to the view.